# LAUNCHER Client Not Ready Yet.. Waiting for Process to Come Online

Tags: java, android, android-studio, debugging

Dears, can you help me with my problem as it's my first time using this software, and I wanted to download my application on my phone, but it kept showing some errors. I have read some of the familiar cases but couldn't figure it out. so can you help me, please !

[My code, and I've highlighted the error that keeps showing up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZEXv.png)
[This is what appears on my phone when i run the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKMkT.png)

Answer (score 0):

This looks OK, debugging always slows down the app, and you will have to wait for a bit. You can go faster using some of the available emulator to test it on your computer. Try [genymotion](http://genymotion.com/), also you can even try [bluestacks](http://bluestacks.zendesk.com/).

Comment: can you give me the URL for that software please, i guess there is no free version of it, if im not mistaken

Comment: @MohamedAl-attar I updated my answer with links to both of those links, hope it will help :)

Comment: the genymotion software program is no longer available as free version.